# Spotfire Case statement not working

Tags: data-analysis, spotfire, case-statement

I am trying to write a case statement in which I want to categorise my column values into 4 cases. But only 1 case got created-"HV-HM". The code is:

```
case 
WHEN Sum([Sales])/UniqueCount([Quarter])>=${HighVolume} and Avg([Net 
Margin])>=${HighMargin} THEN "HV-HM"
WHEN Sum([Sales])/UniqueCount([Quarter])>=${HighVolume} and (Avg([Net 
Margin])<${HighMargin}) and Avg([Net Margin])>${LosingMargin} THEN "HV-LM"
WHEN Sum([Sales])/UniqueCount([Quarter])<${HighVolume} And Avg([Net Margin])
<${HighMargin} And Avg([Net Margin])>${LosingMargin} THEN "LV-LM"
WHEN Avg([Net Margin])<=${LosingMargin} THEN "Losing"
END as [Sector]
```

Can anyone please fix the issue?

Comment: If possible, could you please post the underlying table with some dummy values?

Answer (score 0):

Too long to comment....

Each case in your statement is unique, so that means the first "case" is met for all of your data. Since you don't think this shouldn't be the case, the best thing to do is break this up into calculated columns so you can see the values. Create a calculated column for each case.

Create a calculated column for these two methods:

```
Sum([Sales])/UniqueCount([Quarter])
Avg([Net Margin])
```

Then, you can manually see if they will be above or below your High and Low margin property controls.

You can also create a calculated column for each case:

```
case when Sum([Sales])/UniqueCount([Quarter])>=${HighVolume} and Avg([Net Margin])>=${HighMargin} then 1 end as [Test 1]
case when Sum([Sales])/UniqueCount([Quarter])>=${HighVolume} and (Avg([Net Margin])<${HighMargin}) and Avg([Net Margin])>${LosingMargin} 1 end as [Test 2]
etc...
```

Comment: Actually am using a scatter plot and trying to color by dividing the columns in these 4 categories by case statement. I tried creating separate calculated columns but still doesnt work..

Comment: The point of creating the separate column was to test logic. What was the results of those columns? Did you have 1 in all columns?